# Should I use Chi-Squared or Fisher's test?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, poisson-regression, fishers-exact-test

everyone. I have a question which involves statistics and the R programming language, thus I believe that this question pertains to this forum, but if any of you know someplace else where I could go to for answers, I'd thank you.

So, I'm helping a friend who's doing her doctorate thesis. Her objective is to evaluate the association of determined genes (with regards to genotypes and gene models) and the use of some medications for the outcome of a disease (in this case, oral mucositis). The experiment is complex, as it envolves a very specific population (children with certain types of cancers), and she has a sample of size 392.

In the literature, there's a study which used chi-square tests to initially evaluate which gene models have an association to the diseases, and then a univariate poisson regression was adjusted for each gene model, followed by a multivariate poisson regression with all the models.

Now, my questions are:

1 - In some contingency tables I have expected values smaller than 5. In this case should I use the Fisher's exact test? If I should use it for some of the contingecy tables, shouldn't I use it for all of them?

2 - For the poisson regression, first I should verify if the poisson distribution is followed by the outcome (which it probably does, since it's a counting variable in the end: the number of pacients who had such outcome). Also, I should verify if the outcome variable has mean equal to variance, right? I read a article in which this property is frequently violated (it's written in portuguese, my mother language, [https://www.scielo.br/j/asoc/a/znrHQvBfVvBRRWyfMyg4Tmy/?lang=pt&format=pdf#:~:text=O%20modelo%20de%20regressão%20de%20Poisson%20tem%20por%20característica%20a,McCULLAGH%3B%20NELDER%2C%201989](https://www.scielo.br/j/asoc/a/znrHQvBfVvBRRWyfMyg4Tmy/?lang=pt&format=pdf#:%7E:text=O%20modelo%20de%20regress%C3%A3o%20de%20Poisson%20tem%20por%20caracter%C3%ADstica%20a,McCULLAGH%3B%20NELDER%2C%201989))., p. 4, last paragraph). Or would it be best to use another model, such as the negative binomial?

Unfortunately I can't provide the dataset, but I believe you should need it, since my questions are more theoretical than practical.

I thank you all for reading through this and possibly answering me.

Comment: ```chisq.test``` in R with ```simulate.p.value=TRUE``` will not use the asymptotic chi sqaured distribution and also work with smaller expected values. Normally one should expect chi squared and Fisher test to give very similar results, so I'd try out both, and if results are the same you have a clear picture, if not chances are p-values are pretty inconclusive anyway. Model assumptions can never be "verified"; at best there's no evidence against them. Always look at your data to see whether potential violations are mild or striking.

Comment: It may be helpful to look at the different ways the table margins are handled by the chi-square test of association, Fisher's exact test, and Bernard's test: ( [en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnard%27s_test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnard%27s_test) ).  I don't know how a Monte Carlo simulation fits into this framework....  Practically speaking, it may not matter much, especially considering that you are using the analysis of the contingency tables as a screen for further analysis.

Comment: My understanding is that the negative binomial model is a more general case of a Poisson model, so the negative binomial may be a good choice if you are not sure about the Poisson assumptions.